# How to overwrite an objects values using an array php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following array containing one or more **objects**:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => ApiS7File {#484 ▼
    +id: 19
    +type: "file"
    +z: "e1a4f81f.f90428"
    +name: ""
    +filename: "example/example.txt"
  }
]
```

If the user suplies me with an options array

```
$options = ['filename' => 'hello', 'name' => 'thanks']
```

I want the array object to be overwritten using the user suplied values:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => ApiS7File {#484 ▼
    +id: 19
    +type: "file"
    +z: "e1a4f81f.f90428"
    +name: "thanks"
    +filename: "hello"
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is ApiS7File instanceof ArrayObject?

Comment: will the user-supplied array only contain valid keys? or do you need to validate the supplied data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might solve your problem.

```
//assuming $arr is your array

foreach($arr as $a){
   foreach($options as $key=>$value){
       $a->$key = $value;
   }
}
return $arr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_replace,

```
$result = array_replace($yourArray, $options);
```

Here is syntax for the same

```
$basket = array_replace($base, $replacements,// you can pass multiple arrays);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the array_replace does not work because the array contains an object and is therefore not an array :-)